# What am I doing wrong w/ overlap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand what am i doing wrong. The iphone bottom part should be covered by the white section. When i add position:absolute the img just gets bigger as it's taken out of the flow. I gave it's parent div class parent and added position:relative but still doesnt work. Please help me if you can. Thank you

```css
body{
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}



h1{
  font-family: "Montserrat-Bold";
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5;

}
h2{
  font-family: "Montserrat-Bold";
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 900;
}
h3{
  font-family: "Montserrat-Bold";
  font-weight: 900;
}
p{
  color: #8f8f8f;
}

/* Navigation Bar */

.navbar{
  padding: 0 0 4.5rem;
}

.navbar-brand{
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-item{
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav-link{
  font-family: "Montserrat-light";
  font-size: 1.2rem;

}

/* Download Buttons */

.download-button{
margin: 5% 3% 5% 0;
}

/* Title Selection */

#title{
  background-color: #ff4c68;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

#title .container-fluid{
  padding: 3% 7% 15%;

}



/* Title Image */

.parent{
  position: relative;

}
.title-image{
  width: 60%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 50%;

}

/* Features Section */

#features{
  padding: 7% 15%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;


}

.feature-box{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4.5%;
}

.icon{
  color: #ef8172;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.icon:hover{
  color: #ff4c68;
}

/* Testimonials Section */

#testimonials{

  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ef8172;
  color: #fff;

}
.testimonial-text{
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.testimonial-image{
width: 10%;
border-radius: 100%;
margin: 20px;
}

.carousel-item{
  padding: 7% 15%;
}

#press{
  background-color: #ef8172;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3%;

}
.press-logo{
width: 15%;
margin: 20px 20px 50px;
}

/* Pricing */

#pricing{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px;
}

.pricing-column{
  padding: 3% 2%;
}
@media (max-width: 1028px){

  #title{
    text-align: center;
  }
  .title-image{
    position: static;
    margin: auto;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather&family=Montserrat:wght@100;400;900&family=Sacramento&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b5b3a56b48.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- BootStrap -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</head>


<body>

  <section id="title">

    <div class="container-fluid">


      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" gref="">tindog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href=""> Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href=""> Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href=""> Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>


      <!-- Title -->

      <div class="parent row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="title-image" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="icon fa-solid fa-circle-check fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
        <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="icon fa-solid fa-bullseye fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="icon fa-solid fa-heart fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>


  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>

      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>

  </section>


  <!-- Press -->

  <section id="press">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

  </section>


  <!-- Pricing -->

<section id="pricing">

  <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
  <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>



  <div class="row">

      <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2>Free</h2>
          <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
          <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark btn-block w-100" type="button">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>Labrador</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
          <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
          <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark w-100" type="button">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>Mastiff</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
          <p>Pirority Listing</p>
          <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
          <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark w-100" type="button">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



<!-- <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 mb-3 text-center">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h3 class="my-0 fw-normal">Chihuahua</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">Free<small class="text-muted fw-light"></small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
             <h2>Free</h2>
          <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
          <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark">Sign up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h3 class="my-0 fw-normal">Labrador</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">49<small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
          <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
          <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-dark">Sign up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
        <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h3 class="my-0 fw-normal">Mastiff</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$99<small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
             <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
          <li><p>Pirority Listing</p></li>
          <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
          <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-dark">Sign up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
-->










  </section>


  <!-- Call to Action -->

  <section id="cta">

    <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
    <button type="button">Download</button>
    <button type="button">Download</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer">

    <p>© Copyright TinDog</p>

  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

**strong text**

Comment: Can you show an image of desired outcome?

Answer (score 1):

I would need more details to which class you are trying to apply `position absolute` to, so therefor I cannot give a definitive answer. Although, usually ***when an element is increased due to another element, it mostly because the parent container height is not set.*** When you do not set a height on an element, the ***height by default is set to auto***, so this means it will automatically enlarge/increase if the size of it's child element increases. I may get downvotes or flack for this, but that's okay. Just a shot in the dark. Bottom line is, *try setting a fixed height to the parent container of you're image and see if that works.* for ex:

```
.wrapper{
   height: 200px
}

<div class="wrapper>
   <img src"/https:/childElement/"/>
</div>
```

So basically no matter how much the child element is increased, it should not go above more than 100% or 200px.

---

**update**

The issue is caused by not having a set height that matching your width on your image.

Add this:

```
.title-image{
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      transform: rotate(25deg);
      position: absolute;
      margin-right: 50%;
    }
```

this fixed it. If you do not like the size, adjust it to your own accord but make sure the height & width match so the image does not look a bit weird. If you set the height to 500px then the wdith needs to be 500px for ex.

Comment: I’m adding it to title-image in css. 
I also added position relative to it’s parent.

Comment: I see, running the code now.. is it the fact that the horizontal scroll bar pops up at the bottom when you set the position to absolute? I just want to make sure that is the actual issue you are facing

Comment: Thank you for your time helping me out. The title-image ( I don’t know how to add a link in here) it’s an iPhone picture. When I set it to position absolut gets blow out of proportion. If I set it to relative it’s almost perfect. I  have it rotated to 45deg and I would like to have the bottom corner underneath the white section

Comment: no problem, I found the solution, I had to outsource my own image in order to recreate the scenario. the problem is you did not set a height and matching width, that is why it was dynamically changing. I will post the answer above in a few.

Comment: updated post above. that should solve it. In the future, try using z-index instead of positioning element when you can.

Comment: Awesome. this worked. I did give it a 60%width but for whatever reason didn't work. I did w300px and h 600px and now its perfect and responsive. Again, Thank you